# can I use bootstrap css and javascript on office add in API

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, office365, office-addins, word-addins

can I use bootstrap framework on office add in API
boostrap css instead of fabric
also if yes am I will face any problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely no problem to use bootstrap or any css library on an office.js add-in.
Remember an add-in is just a web page with a js library : office.js that helps you to communicate with Office host.